# Need help finding this DM tool!

Tags: tools, product-identification, miniatures, props

First time post here. I have been running a game for over a year and a half now and am on technically my 3rd campaign. I am trying to introduce more visual elements to the table that would not be expensive miniatures. I came across this photo posted in another question -(([What are some alternatives to using miniatures for games that require them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/what-are-some-alternatives-to-using-miniatures-for-games-that-require-them/62483#62483))) but because of the way this site is set up I couldn't directly ask the person who posted it - Being new to this. So I thought I would cast my net a little wider -

[image]

Printing color transparencies like this would be a fantastic and perfect solution for me and I was wondering if anyone knew where to find or purchase top down image files like this - or do these not really exist?

I do not know where else to look - I feel like this could easily be a real photo or concept one and ANY help with this will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are called "tokens" (sometimes "creature tokens" or "monster tokens") and are widely available in PDF at all fine purveyors of roleplaying games PDFs, such as [RPGNow](http://www.rpgnow.com/browse.php?keywords=Token&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=). Normally these are used with virtual tabletop software or printed onto card stock and cut out for use on a real tabletop, but if you have access to an appropriate printer and transparent stock, you can certainly print them on transparencies.