# What is a good way to get a large range of fantasy miniatures?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, adnd-2e, fantasy, miniatures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find fantasy minis on the cheap?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/where-can-i-find-fantasy-minis-on-the-cheap)

I am looking to start a collection of miniatures. I mostly want one or two of a lot of different creatures, such as for example 2 orcs, 2 lizardmen, an ogre and 2 goblins, rather than (say) 20 orcs.

I tried looking on the internet, but I couldn't find any bulk (read 'cheap') miniatures that had a range of different creatures. I'm looking for just fantasy miniatures - AD&D 2e to be precise, but other systems that include creatures in D&D are also good.

I can't go to a FLGS, as I don't have one. I also tried ebay, but the search mechanism kept trying to sell me scenery.

**Where can I find something like this?**

Comment: You might check out the answers to this question:http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/where-can-i-find-fantasy-minis-on-the-cheap?rq=1